# apns: localize close Button

Tags: apple-push-notifications

In the following apns  sample :

```
{"aps" : {"alert":{"body":"my message","action-loc-key":"Jouer"}
```

the body(message) and the action-loc-key(view button) can be localised(customised)
They will show in PN as written. But also in PN there will be a left Button showing 'Close'
The PN will look like:

```
    my message
Close       Jouer
```

How the Close button (the left one) can be customized?

Can you give an example where the Close Button would show like 'Ferme' ?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developers have no control over the left button of the push notification. If you've set up your localization properly, the close button will be localized automatically.